# Four points on a projective line with projective transformation that switches places of pairs of points.

Tags: matrices, inverse, projective-geometry

"Let A,B,C,D be four points on a projective line. Show that there's a projective transformation which switches places of A and C, and also B and D."

My thinking was that if I have a known projective line where I have a known projective transformation that does the switch, then I could just have that all projective lines can be mapped to (with inverse) any other projective line, and then the switch property would be true for every line, since I can map it to the known line, apply the 'switch' projective transformation, and then use the inverse map to go back to the original line.

The particular line and transformation that I thought of is x+y-z=0 and (x,y,z) -> (y,x,z).

Is my thinking correct? Does this prove it?

Comment: So what are $A,B,C,D$?

Comment: A,B,C,D are points on the complex projective plane. Homogenous coordinates.

Comment: So how does your transformation switch them?

Comment: It switches y with x, which for the line x+y-z=0 does not make the equation invalid. Now we can set like, A = (1,2,3), and then C = (2,1,3) for example. If you do the transformation to any of them you get the other. To show that there are atleast 2 pairs, I'll set z=0, which will give a B such that B is not a scalar multiplied with A or C. B = (1,-1,0), D then becomes (-1,1,0). These are just examples showing how the switch happens. If "switch" is unclear language, it just means that if we call the transformation F, then F(A) = C, F(C) = A, F(B) = D, F(D) = B.

Comment: Just curious .. what course is this for?  What textbook are you using?

Comment: The coursebook is Conics and Cubics by Bix.

Comment: To prove it, you'd have to show that the round trip from original line to switch on known line back to original line is projective.  So no, you haven't proven it.